# PWA create custom origin for custom project

Tags: custom, magento2.3.5, pwa, pwa-studio

I having an issue with create custom origin it doesn't seem to be reading .env file from my project folder but I have a .env file and it's all set.

Create Project REF: https://magento.github.io/pwa-studio/pwa-buildpack/reference/buildpack-cli/create-project/

`yarn buildpack create-custom-origin package/custom-pwa`

`$ /Users/juliano/Sites/pwa-sites/pwa-studio/node_modules/.bin/buildpack create-custom-origin package/custom-pwa ⓧ  Missing required environment variables: MAGENTO_BACKEND_URL: Connect to an instance of Magento 2.3 by specifying its public domain name. (eg. "https://master-7rqtwti-mfwmkrjfqvbjk.us-4.magentosite.cloud/") CHECKOUT_BRAINTREE_TOKEN: Specify a Braintree API token to direct the Venia storefront to communicate with your Braintree instance. You can find this value in Braintree's Control Panel under Settings > API Keys > Tokenization Keys. (eg. "sandbox_8yrzsvtm_s2bg8fs563crhqzk") ⓧ  Error: Missing required environment variables: MAGENTO_BACKEND_URL: Connect to an instance of Magento 2.3 by specifying its public domain name. (eg. "https://master-7rqtwti-mfwmkrjfqvbjk.us-4.magentosite.cloud/") CHECKOUT_BRAINTREE_TOKEN: Specify a Braintree API token to direct the Venia storefront to communicate with your Braintree instance. You can find this value in Braintree's Control Panel under Settings > API Keys > Tokenization Keys. (eg. "sandbox_8yrzsvtm_s2bg8fs563crhqzk") ⓧ  Error: Error: Missing required environment variables: MAGENTO_BACKEND_URL: Connect to an instance of Magento 2.3 by specifying its public domain name. (eg. "https://master-7rqtwti-mfwmkrjfqvbjk.us-4.magentosite.cloud/") CHECKOUT_BRAINTREE_TOKEN: Specify a Braintree API token to direct the Venia storefront to communicate with your Braintree instance. You can find this value in Braintree's Control Panel under Settings > API Keys > Tokenization Keys. (eg. "sandbox_8yrzsvtm_s2bg8fs563crhqzk")`

All of the above is specified in inside project `package/custom-pwa/.env`

any ideas what could be ?

Answer (score 0):

Found out I was missing .  Sounds a bit stupid even thought I `cd custom-pwa` folder It's required to specify . E.G:

`yarn buildpack create-custom-origin package/custom-pwa .`